# Julia: What are the likely reasons for a method not being able to access a convert method?

Tags: julia

I have a module - lets call it `MyMod` - that contains a `mutable struct MyType`. In the same source file I define functions associated with `MyType`. One of these functions is `Base.convert(::Type{Vector{T}}, a::MyType) where T <: Real`. Another, later on, is `my_func(a::MyType)`. `my_func` internally uses said `convert` function.

I can try these out using the Julia REPL:

```
push!(LOAD_PATH, "path/to/src/")
import MyMod

# Lets check our convert method exists:
hasmethod(convert, Tuple{Type{Vector{Float64}}, MyMod.MyType})
# Returns true

# Make an instance of MyType
a = MyType(1,2,3)
# And we can convert this using our method that we know exists:
convert(Vector{Float64}, a)
# Returns 1.0, 2.0, 3.0. Great.

# How about that function that we made?
MyMod.my_func(a)
# ERROR: MethodError: no method matching convert(::Type{Array{Float64, 1}}, ::MyMod.MyType) 
# You may have intended to import Base.convert
```

So I can find and use a `convert` function from the REPL, but other functions cannot use this `convert`? What reasons could there be for this?

EDIT:

Having spent some time trying to cut down my source code to the minimum that can reproduce the problem I have found and fixed the culprit.

In a different file in the source I have

```
function convert(::Type{Vector{MyTypeB}}, a::MyTypeC)
```

By changing this to

```
function Base.convert(::Type{Vector{MyTypeB}}, a::MyTypeC)
```

The problem detailed above can be fixed.

Comment: Can you post a fully reproducible example because what you describe should work (I have just checked).

Comment: I agree that it should work, which is why I am somewhat surprised. I'm trying to avoid making this specific to my source code, but I'll see what I can strip out and still have this reproducible to avoid you having to clone a large library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shadowed the function. If you define something like

```
> convert(::Type{Float64},x) = 2
convert (generic function with 1 method)

> convert(Float64,5)
2
```

Now `convert` and `Base.convert` are different. If you meant to add dispatches to `Base.convert`, then you should do `Base.convert(x,y) = ...`.

Notice that if you use a function first, Julia will warn you that:

```
> convert(Float64,2)
2.0

> convert(::Type{Float64},x) = 2
ERROR: error in method definition: function Base.convert must be explicitly imported to be extended
Stacktrace:
 [1] top-level scope at none:0
```